# how to rewrite this url http://www.example.com/?user=xxx&search=xxx&page=2

Tags: php, .htaccess

http://www.example.com/?user=xxx&search=xxx&page=2

I want this style rewrite. Please help me

http://www.example.com/xxxx?search=xxx&page=2

Comment: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/redirect-generator.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite using the .htaccess route with mod_rewrite.

Add a file called .htaccess in your root folder, and add something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/xxxx?search=xxx&page=2 ^/?user=xxx&search=xxx&page=2
```

This will tell Apache to enable mod_rewrite for this folder, and if it gets asked a URL matching the regular expression it rewrites it internally to what you want, without the end user seeing it.